# Laravel - Fontawesome no me muestra los iconos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7, font-awesome

tengo un proyecto con laravel 7 y he instalado fontawesome pero no consigo que me salgan los iconos.

Tengo esta configuración

**app.scss**

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.css";
@import "../vendor/twitter-boostrap/bootstrap.css";
@import "../vendor/twitter-boostrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css";

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
    
@import "style";
```

Os muestro lo que obtengo por pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Webpack lo tengo de esta forma, me genera un fichero **css/app.css**

```
mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/chartjs/Chart.bundle.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/chartjs/utils.js',
], 'public/js/app.js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

Veo que me da un error al intentar cargar los archivos woff y ttf (las fuentes???)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

Comment: ¿Esto no es erróneo: `'~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';`? ¿No debería ser **`fontawesome`** en lugar de `fortawesome`? El error se estaría repitiendo en los cuatro `import` ...

Comment: He probado con este otro comando.

npm install font-awesome --save-dev y luego $fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

Comment: ¿Qué me dices de lo que te comenté anteriormente? ¿Por qué intentas otra instalación? ¿No lo tenías ya instalado?

Comment: He probado lo que me has dicho y me hace lo mismo. Es laravel7

Comment: Yo lo importo así  `@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";` y me funciona.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ acabo de editar el primer post, he visto que me da un error al cargar los archivos woff.

Answer (score 0):

La solución ha sido poniendo esta sentencia en el fichero webpack.mix.js

```
mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts', 'public/webfonts');
```

**Al final los 2 ficheros me han quedado de esta forma.**

**Fichero app.scss**

```
// Fontawesome-free@5.12.1
$fa-font-path: "../webfonts";

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
```

**Webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setResourceRoot("../");

mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts', 'public/webfonts');

mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app.js',
        'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
        'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    ], 'public/js/app.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    });
```